# Regla con nginx para diferentes carpetas

Tags: linux, apache, servidor, nginx, apache2

tengo un proyecto muy simple con php sin ningún framework detrás y tengo una estructura como esta, tengo una carpeta /modulos/promociones y dentro tengo N páginas por ejemplo estas

```
ford-escort-1990.php
ford-escort-1993.php
seat-ibiza-mk1-1990.php
seat-ibiza-mk2-1996.php
```

En el servidor tengo instalado nginx con lo que tengo esta configuración para el site.

```
location / {
  if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$http_host$1 redirect;
  }
  rewrite ^/([a-z\-\\/\A-Z]+)$ /index.php?mod=$1;
  rewrite ^/([a-z\-\\/\A-Z]+)/$ /index.php?mod=$1;
}
```

Con esto consigo que si la url es http://www.ejemplo.com/promociones/ford-escort-1990/ seria lo equivalente
http://www.ejemplo.com/index.php?mod=promociones/ford-escort-1990.php

Esto esta funcionando, pero quiero hacer una mejora ya que tengo muchos archivos en este directorio y me gustaria crear carpetas por año tipo esto
/modulos/promociones/1990
/modulos/promociones/1993
/modulos/promociones/1996

Como tengo los archivos con este formato "nombre+año".php y el final del archivo siempre es un numero (1990, 1996, etc), como podria hacer una regla
con nginx que si hago esta llamada

http://www.ejemplo.com/promociones/ford-escort-1990/ me cargue -> http://www.ejemplo.com/index.php?mod=promociones/1990/ford-escort.php

Y si tengo esta otra
http://www.ejemplo.com/promociones/ford-escort-1996/ me cargue -> http://www.ejemplo.com/index.php?mod=promociones/1996/ford-escort.php

Gracias.